# Limits and Trigonometry

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Consider an function $f$ , defined as :

$$f^k (\theta) =\sum_{r=1}^n \left( \frac{\tan \left( \frac {\theta}{2^r} \right) }{2^r} \right)^k +\frac 1 3 \sum _{r=1}^n \left( \frac { \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2^r} \right) }{8^r} \right)$$

Again define an function, $L$:

$$L(\theta )=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty } \left( \sum_{k=1}^3 f^k (\theta) \right) $$

Hints

Hint-1)- Try to prove this elementary and standard result:

$$\boxed { \prod_{k=1}^n \cos \left( \frac{\theta}{2^k} \right) =\frac {\sin\theta}{ 2^n \sin \left( \frac{\theta}{2^n} \right) } } $$

Hint-2)- Think how to convert product into sum. (Take logarithm to base e)

Hint-3)- After converting into sum , Differentiate 3 times (with some smart manipulations), and note down each derivatives.

Expressions: (Try to Prove it)

Exp-1)-
$$ \boxed { \sum_{r=1}^n \left( \frac { \tan \left( \cfrac {\theta}{2^r} \right) }{2^r} \right) =\frac {1}{2^n \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2^n} \right) } -\frac{1}{\tan\theta} } $$

Exp-2)-
$$ \boxed { \sum_{r=1}^n \left( \frac {\tan \left( \frac {\theta}{2^r} \right)}{ 2^r } \right)^2 =\frac { 1 }{ \sin^2 \theta } -\frac { 1 }{ 4^n \sin^2 \left( \frac {\theta}{2^n} \right) } -\frac { 4^n -1 }{ 3\times4^n} } $$

Exp-3)-
$$\boxed { \sum_{r=1}^n \left( \frac { \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2^r} \right) }{2^r} \right)^3 +\sum_{r=1}^n \left( \cfrac { \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2^r} \right) }{8^r} \right) =\frac{1}{ 8^n \sin^2 \left( \frac{\theta}{2^n} \right) \tan \left( \frac {\theta}{2^n} \right) } -\csc^2 \theta \cot \theta } $$

Final Result

Closed form of $L(\theta)$ is ,:

$$\boxed { L(\theta )=\frac {1}{\theta^3} -\frac{2}{\theta^2} -\frac 1 3 +\csc^2 \theta (1-\cot \theta )-\cot \theta }$$ I was given the aforementioned hints, but was still unable to solve the problem.
Could somebody please tell me how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: One seldom sees MathJax code written as badly as this.  Obviously it was done by one of those softwares that writes the code for you.  If an actual human wrote code like this, I'd diagnose him as psychotic.

Comment: Sir, I've made the code alright. Actually, I used the Latex coding which uses \\( \\) or \\[ \\] at first.

Comment: I've immensely simplified the code.  All the complications that have no effect on the appearance can only make editing more difficult.

Comment: Yes Sir, I saw that. Thanks very much, and I'm truly sorry for the trouble you had to take.

Answer (score 1):

The elementary and standard result can be written (in long hand fashion) as
$$\cos \left( \frac{\theta}{2^1} \right)\times {\cos \left( \frac{\theta}{2^2} \right)\times\cdots\times \cos \left( \frac{\theta}{2^n} \right)=\frac {\sin\theta}{ 2^n \sin \left( \frac{\theta}{2^n} \right) } }$$ 
Let's start from hint $(2)$, we use the following identity:
$$\log(x_1\times x_2 \times \cdots \times x_2)=\log(x_1)+ \log(x_2) + \cdots +\log(x_n)=\sum_{r=1}^n\log(x_r)$$
to take the natural log of both sides:-
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)\right)=\log(\sin \theta)-\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\right)-\log(2^n)$$ 
Differentiating both sides, we use the identity that $\frac{d}{d\theta}\log(f(\theta))=\frac{f'(\theta)}{f(\theta)}$.

For the left hand side, we have 
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{d\theta}\sum_{r=1}^n\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)\right)&=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{d}{d\theta}\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)\right)\\&=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\color{blue}{\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)\right)}}{\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}\\&=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\color{blue}{-\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}}{\color{blue}{2^r}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}\\&=-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\end{align}$$

For the right hand side, we use similar principles to differentiate, leading to the first derivative being:- 
$$-\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)=\frac{1}{\tan \theta}-\frac{1}{2^n\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}\\\Rightarrow \sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}-\frac{1}{\tan \theta}$$ 
Differentiating a second time, we use the result that $\frac{d}{d\theta}\tan\theta=\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta$ and $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{1}{\tan\theta})=\frac{d}{d\theta}\cot\theta=-\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta=-\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}$, leading to
$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{4^r}\right)&=\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}-\frac{1}{4^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}\\\Rightarrow\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)^2&=\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}-\frac{1}{4^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}-\color{blue}{\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{4^r}}\\&=\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}-\frac{1}{4^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}-\color{blue}{\frac{4^n-1}{3\times4^n}}\end{align}$$
where the term highlighted in blue is a sum of a geometric progression.

For the third (and final) derivative, we use the chain rule and re-use the rule for the derivative of a tan function.

Let's focus on the derivative of the LHS:-
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{d\theta}\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)^2&=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)^2\\&=\sum_{r=1}^n2\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)
\color{blue}{\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)}
\\&=\sum_{r=1}^n2\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)
\color{blue}{\left(\frac{\sec^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{4^r}\right)}
\\&=2\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)
\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{4^r}\right)}\end{align}$$

The RHS is more straightforward to differentiate, so the third differential is:- 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^n2\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)\left(\frac{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{4^r}\right)&=-\frac{2\cos \theta}{\sin^3\theta}+\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}{8^n\sin^3\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}\\\Rightarrow\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{2^r}\right)^3+\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^r}\right)}{8^r}\right)&=\frac{1}{8^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}-\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta\cot\theta\end{align}$$
Having calculated the three derivatives, the defined function $L$ is simply the sum of the three derivatives with $n$ tending to $\infty$ - we simply add the Right Hand Side (RHS) of the three derivatives, leading to
$$\begin{align}L(\theta)&=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{1}{2^n\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}-\frac{1}{\tan \theta}+\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}-\frac{1}{4^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}-\frac{4^n-1}{3\times4^n}+\frac{1}{8^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}-\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta\cot\theta\right)\\&=\frac{1}{\theta^3}-\frac{1}{\theta^2}+\frac{1}{\theta}-\frac{1}{3}+\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta(1-\cot\theta)-\cot\theta\end{align}$$
where the small angle approximation is used for the sine and tangent functions, so that $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\approx\frac{\theta}{2^n}$ and $\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\approx\frac{\theta}{2^n}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Note: I end up with a slightly different answer to what is in the question.

Comment: I'm really sorry Sir, but I couldn't understand properly. Could you please give some more detail (perhaps some sort of working out of the steps so I could understand - I find it really hard to understand operations performed on Sigma and Pi notations), at your convenience? I would be truly grateful if you would please do so. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sir,  could you please explain the last derivative? I didn't understand how you differentiated the last summation.
Also, how do they sum up to $$f^k (\theta) =\sum_{r=1}^n \left( \frac{\tan \left( \frac {\theta}{2^r} \right) }{2^r} \right)^k +\frac 1 3 \sum _{r=1}^n \left( \frac { \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2^r} \right) }{8^r} \right)$$
What about the 'to the power $k$' in the first term of RHS? Sir, I'm really confused:(

Comment: @Djokofan: I have added a few steps to my answer. The first, second and third differentials add up to $\sum_{k=1}^3f^k (\theta) $, which is what you need to calculate $L(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a justification of the expression in hint 1. You have to use one of Simpsons formula:
\begin{equation}
\cos(x)\sin(y)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin(x+y) - \sin(x-y) \right]
\end{equation}
I'm going to prove that $2^n\sin(\theta/2^n)\prod \cos(\theta/2^k)=\sin(\theta)$:
\begin{equation}
2^n\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\prod \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^k}\right)=2^n\cos(\theta)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)
\end{equation}
Using Simpsons formula $\displaystyle\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)$:
\begin{equation}
2^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)\prod \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^k}\right)=2^{n-1}\cos(\theta)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=2^{n-2}\cos(\theta)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\dots\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-2}}\right)
\end{equation}
Repeat this $n$ times. Eventually you get $\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Thanks Sir. But then how do we use this to get the answer?

Comment: I've tried to find prove expression (1), but without success :-(